# MOSS Upload Size?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, sharepoint-2007

In MOSS we have done all of this to increase the file upload size, reset iis but still doesnt want to play = anyone any advice.

**UPDATE**

Just seen the Scott Gu article - [http://weblogs.asp.net/pscott/archive/2009/02/26/404-errors-with-fileupload-with-iis7.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/pscott/)  and JS example
http://msmvps.com/blogs/cgross/archive/2009/02/25/large-files-in-sbs-2008-s-companyweb.aspx

So need to say this is II6 on win2k3

**Update 2**

still not working at a loss anyone help?

> 1. In SharePoint 3.0 Central Adminisration, Application Management
>      tab, and
>      Web application general settings configure the Maximum upload size to a
>      maximum of 2047 MB. - **We set ours to 250MB**
>
>    2. In Internet Information Services on the properties of the
>         virtual server
>         increase the Connection Timeout to greater than default 120 seconds
>         depending
>         on the time to upload large files in your environment for example, 360
>         seconds. - **We set ours to 600 Secs**
>    3. Configure the web.config for the _layouts web.config with
>         On the SharePoint server change C:\Program Files\Common
>         Files\Microsoft
>         Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\web.config
>         with an
>         executionTimeout appropriate for the file size you are uploading.
>         An example is included below.
>         from:  
>            to:
>         executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="2097151" />

Comment: updated my answer with link.

Comment: Apart from the iis7 specific part the rest should work for ii6

Comment: nope didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to change some of the config values via STSADM

[Max-file-post-size: Stsadm property (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261801.aspx)

and

[Large-file-chunk-size: Stsadm property (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262061.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add the following to your web.config

```
 </System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler>
    <system.webServer>
     <security>
      <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="262144000" />
      </requestFiltering>
     </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/cgross/archive/2009/02/25/large-files-in-sbs-2008-s-companyweb.aspx) for original article

Comment: Hi JS do you have the link to the orginal article?

Comment: thanks - jsut updated to say that this is on ii6 - not iis7 but thanks